# Extracting raster values from ALL pixels

Tags: r, extract

I have a large raster file from which I want to extract the raster values of ALL pixels present in the file. How do I do this in R?

Comment: Do you just want a vector of values or a set of values with their x,y locations (at the centre of the pixels)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `values` function. Here's an example for a small raster in the `raster` package:

```
> library(raster)
> r = raster(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
> values(r)
 [1]  1  4  7 10  2  5  8 11  3  6  9 12
```

or in the `terra` package you get a matrix with one column per layer:

```
> library(terra)
terra 1.6.18
> r = rast(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
> values(r)
      lyr.1
 [1,]     1
 [2,]     4
 [3,]     7
 ....
```

There's nothing in the help that says this doesn't work for large raster files, and you've not actually said how large your large raster file is, so I think you'll have to try it.

Answer (score 2):

Not extraction per se but, converting to a different data format. In terra it is as simple as coercing to point data using `as.points`, which will result in a terra vect class object. If you want an sf class object just wrap it in `st_as_sf`. Be forewarned, the raster format exists for good reason. Point vector files representing millions, if not billions, of observations is very cumbersome and difficult to work with.

Comment: Yes its not clear if they want the values without context or a set of (x, y, value) triples...